# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build with navigation in Inkwell

Tags: flutter

I am making a login page with a inkwell that navigate to forget password page.
without adding the code of navigation, It works well.
Once I put the navigation code, an error appear " setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." and then the next page appear without tapping the button.

this is the start of Login page:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
 }

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
 final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

String email = "", password = "", passwordErrorText, emailErrorText;
 FocusNode emailFocus, passwordFocus;

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();

emailFocus = FocusNode();
passwordFocus = FocusNode();
passwordErrorText = null;
emailErrorText = null;
emailFocus.addListener(() {
  if (!emailFocus.hasFocus) {
    if (!TextFieldValidator().emailValidator.isValid(email.toLowerCase())) {
      setState(() {
        emailErrorText = TextFieldValidator().emailValidator.errorText;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        emailErrorText = null;
      });
    }
  }
   });
 }
```

and this is the button:

```
         Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                forgetPassText,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              onTap: Router.goToForgetPassword(context),
            ))
      ])),
```

and this is the function that navigate

```
static goToForgetPassword(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.push(
    context,
    PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
          ForgetPasswordPage(),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        return child;
      },
    ));
```

}

Comment: you are not closing the initState{} function and you are doing everything inside the initialization (building) of the app and thats not the right way:  @override
void initState() {
super.initState();

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very simple: you are calling the function, you should be giving a function that calls the function. So this line should become:

```
              onTap: () => Router.goToForgetPassword(context),
```

Earlier, you were calling `goToForgetPassword` and giving to `onTap` whatever it returns (probably null). But now we are creating a function to be called in the future, and giving that function to be called to `onTap`.

If you can put a breakpoint inside `goToForgetPassword` function and debug, you will also see this for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                forgetPassText,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              onTap: Router.goToForgetPassword(context),
            ))
      ])),
```

by

```
 Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                forgetPassText,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              onTap: () => Router.goToForgetPassword(context),
            ))
      ])),
```

In this case the `InkWell` will wait for the click , not launching the function while rendering.